# how can I make a slug using fields from a different table using sluggable behaviour in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a Campaign model and I want to create a slug for each new campaign. I can do this easily with sluggable behaviour which is awesome but I'd like the slug to be created from the first_name and last_name field in the users table.

How can I do this? I've seen it asked a couple of times online but never answered. Surely it's possible!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a relationship where Campaign belongsTo User, then in your Campaign model, just override the beforeValidate() function. You can override beforeSave() instead, but you will not get validation on the slug.  Anyway:

```
function beforeValidate() {
    $return = parent::beforeValidate();

    if(isset($this->data['User']['first_name']) && isset($this->data['User']['last_name'])) {
        // assumes we're saving a campaign and a user at the same time w/ saveAll
        $this->data['Campaign']['slug'] = $this->data['User']['first_name'] . ' ' . $this->data['User']['last_name'];
    } elseif(isset($this->data['Campaign']['user_id'])) {
        // saving Campaign record w/ just user_id passed
        $user = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('User.id'=>$this->data['Campaign']['user_id']), 'fields'=>array('User.first_name', 'User.last_name')));
        if($user) {
            $this->data['Campaign']['slug'] = $user['User']['first_name'] . ' ' . $user['User']['last_name'];
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: This solution looks good although I didn't want to have to save the campaign and user at the same time. At the moment I have a user registration screen and a campaign creation screen. Is there no way to do this using sluggable behaviour but importing the 1stname and 2ndname from the Users table :( I appreciate the suggestions anyway

Comment: This solution doesn't require you to save both at the same time.  I was only handling that use-case.  The elseif portion only requires that a user_id be set in the provided campaign data.

Comment: Who's the daddy! You're brilliant, thank you, thank you, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use the Sluggable behavior? Isn't it easier to use the `Inflector::slug` method with first_name and last_name as parameters? Something like this:

```
$name = sprintf('%s %s', $first_name, $last_name);
$slug = Inflector::slug($name);
$this->Campaign->set('slug', $slug);
$this->Campaign->save();
```

Seems easier to me.

Comment: Yeah possibly. But sluggable does a bunch of checking so forth - like it checks to make sure the slug is unique etc... I'm not sure your suggestion would work for me anyway. first_name and last_name are part of a different model. Surely I can't just call them like that? continued next comment

Comment: Is there not some way I can load the Users model so I can put <pre>var $actsAs = array('Sluggable' => array('label'=> array('User.first_name', 'User.last_name'), 'separator' => '_', 'overwrite' => true));</pre>

Comment: You can do the same check of course on the User model. I understand that the 'all-in-one' solution of the Behaviour is nice, but I guess you're better off emulating some of it's functionality in a new method than trying to make your way fit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use the sluggable behavior and both fields are from the same model - the solution I have used in the past is to:

a) Set up a virtual field for the User model

```
<?php
    class User extends AppModel
    {
        var $virtualFields = array(
            'full_name' => 'CONCAT(User.first_name, " ", User.last_name)'
        );
        ...
    }
?>
```

b) Use the Sluggable behavior on the virtualField.

```
<?php
    class User extends AppModel
    {
        ...
        public $actsAs = array(
            'Sluggable' => array(
                'label' => 'full_name',
                ...
            ),
            ...
        );
    }
?>
```

Comment: Looks like I suggested a solution good for only a single model.